# add path into Current URL Location

Tags: javascript

I am coding to change language by using Read with Korea Language

## Example:

## Currently URL is:

http://www.domain.com/EN/index.php

## When user press onClick URL change to:

http://www.domain.com/KO/index.php

I mean that I just want to replace EN to KO then reload page again.

Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Wow... [You should definitely use jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif) on this one.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a just a link? This doesn't really sound like it needs javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *window.location* object to get to the new URL:

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" 
    + window.location.host + window.location.pathname.replace("EN", "KO");
```

Or I guess simpler, just:

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace("/EN/", "/KO/");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you reload the page, why not just use normal a href.

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/KO/index.php">KO</a>
```

Comment: <a href="javascript:window.location.href.replace('/EN/', '/KO/')" >KO</a> or unobtrusively

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load region specific URL check IP filtering for geological locations. Depending upon IP you'll get, load corresponding URL. e.g. You can use :

```
 if(ip address coming from <region>)
  window.location.replace("http://www.domain.com/<region>/index.php");
```